# Wrong view being returned for controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller method that is returning the wrong view.  The view I have is the same name as the controller method "AssignTask.cshtml".  The method is "public virtual ActionResult AssignTask(ManageTaskModel model) "

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult ManageTasks()
{
    try
    {
        var model = new ManageTaskModel ();
        model.assignedPSUsers = Orchestrator.GetAssignedPSUsers();
        return View(model);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("ErrorMsg", e.Message);
    };

    return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
}

[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult ManageTasks(ManageTaskModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    try
    {   //User has seleced the user that they want to see Tasks for
        if (model.selectedUser != null && model.newUser==null)
        {
            model.assignedPSUsers = Orchestrator.GetAssignedPSUsers();
            model.FcvsTaskList = Orchestrator.GetTasksForAssignedPSUser(model.selectedUser);

            return AssignTask(model);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("ErrorMsg", e.Message);
        return View(model);
    }
    return this.RedirectToAction("Index");

}

[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult AssignTask(ManageTaskModel model) 
{ 
    if (model.selectedUser != null && model.newUser == null)
    {


        **return View(model);**  //returning the ManageTask instead of AssignTask View

    }

    return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ManageTasks action you return AssignTask(model). This doesn't work, because the request context still remembers that the user actually called ManageTasks. That's why it returns the view for ManageTasks.

The right way to do it is like that:

```
return RedirectToAction("AssignTask", model); // remember to pass the model here
```

You can see that if you put this line in AssignTask:

```
HttpContext.Request.Path
```

If you access it from ManageTasks using return AssignTask(model), the value will be "/YourController/ManageTasks".

If you either call this action directly from browser or with RedirectToAction the value will be "/YourController/AssignTask".

Comment: You can also specify the view name when you're returning it from another method; otherwise, the view has no name but is returned with the name of the action the user actually called (it's in the MVC route data for the current request).

Answer (score 0):

you can't redirect that way.  instead of return AssignTask you need

```
return RedirectToAction("AssignTask");
```

and pass an id or something there.  you will need to recreate the model in your AssignTask method